# php database query (phpMyAdmin) only brings back one value (the first one) into amcharts

Tags: php, mysql, amcharts

The below php database query (from phpMyAdmin) only brings back one value (the first one or the oldest) into amcharts:

```
<?php
class custom_class2 
{  
    var $charts;    // reference to the calling object.  

    function customfunction2($content,$conf)
    {   
        global $TSFE;        
        $TSFE->set_no_cache();

        // do whatever you want here

        // db connection
        mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password");
        mysql_select_db("database name");

        //db abfrage
        $query = "
            SELECT 
                YEAR(datetime) AS dy, 
                MONTH(datetime) -1 AS dm, 
                DAY(datetime) AS dd, 
                HOUR(datetime) AS th, 
                MINUTE(datetime) AS tm, 
                temp, 
                hum, 
                pressure 
            FROM stock1 
            ORDER BY datetime
        ";

        // NEW: Variable definition 
        $zeilenzaehler = 1;

        // output of the rows
        $result = mysql_query($query) OR die("Error: $query <br>" . mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            // return 
            if ($zeilenzaehler != 1) 
            {
                $content.= ",";
            }

            $content.= "{date: new Date(" . $row['dy'] . "," . $row['dm'] . "," . $row['dd'] . "," . $row['th'] . "," . $row ['tm'] . "),t:" . $row['temp'] . ",h:" . $row['hum'] . ",p:" . $row['pressure'] . "}";

            return $content;

            // Variable now on 2
            $zeilenzaehler = 2;
        }
    }      
} 
?>
```

Everything else looks like its working fine. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You return the first found result in your while-loop. That is why you have just one result. Also as mysql_* functions are depreceted consider switching to
[mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
I am adding code from your request:

```
<?php
class custom_class2
{
     var $charts;    // reference to the calling object.  

     function customfunction2($content,$conf)
     {
         global $TSFE;        
         $TSFE->set_no_cache();

         // do whatever you want here

         // db connection
         $mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database name");
         if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
             // your error handling here
         }

         //db abfrage
         $query = "
            SELECT 
                YEAR(datetime) AS dy, 
                MONTH(datetime) -1 AS dm, 
                DAY(datetime) AS dd, 
                HOUR(datetime) AS th, 
                MINUTE(datetime) AS tm, 
                temp, 
                hum, 
                pressure 
            FROM stock1 
            ORDER BY datetime
         ";

         // NEW: Variable definition 
         $zeilenzaehler = 1;

         // output of the rows
         $result = $mysqli->query($query);
         if (FALSE === $result) {
             // you can put different error handling here
             echo 'Error: ' . $query . ' ' . $mysql->error);
             die();
         }
         $total = array();
         while (NULL !== ($row = $result->fetch_array()))
         {
             // return
             if ($zeilenzaehler != 1)
             {
                 $content.= ",";
             }

             $content.= "{date: new Date(" . $row['dy'] . "," . $row['dm'] . "," . $row['dd'] . "," . $row['th'] . "," . $row ['tm'] . "),t:" . $row['temp'] . ",h:" . $row['hum'] . ",p:" . $row['pressure'] . "}";

             // return $content;
             // if you not return the first result you can gather results in array, so array will contain every row in result, $total[0], $total[1]...:
             // $total[] = $content; or:
             $total[] = "{date: new Date(" . $row['dy'] . "," . $row['dm'] . "," . $row['dd'] . "," . $row['th'] . "," . $row ['tm'] . "),t:" . $row['temp'] . ",h:" . $row['hum'] . ",p:" . $row['pressure'] . "}";

             // Variable now on 2
             $zeilenzaehler = 2;
         }

         $result->free();
         return $total; // return all rows
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Could you provide me exact changes I need to do?

Comment: I can post code with mysqli so you can see what I mean and I'll just remove row where you return data.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working. I use Typo3 and I think it needs to be returned with 'return' as per the docu (http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html)

Comment: That's the error message: "Error: SELECT YEAR(datetime) AS dy, MONTH(datetime) -1 AS dm, DAY(datetime) AS dd, HOUR(datetime) AS th, MINUTE(datetime) AS tm, temp, hum, pressure FROM stock1 ORDER BY datetime"

Comment: I think the error is in query, this is where you die $mysql->query or die()... And finally you can return the whole array $total.